# Spring Tool Suite Jar corrupt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I`m getting below error while opening any file in spring tool suite 4.1.0,
but application is running

---

### Java Virtual Machine Launcher

### Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile G:\Softwares\sts-4.1.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\531\data\1.2.0.201812201040-spring-boot-language-server-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

### OK

[image]

Comment: please include errors as text. Many dialog boxes in windows can have their containing text copied by clicking in the body (just a simple left-click) and pressing `Ctrl + C`

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should have main method in jar to run, must have referenced in MANIFEST.MF.
2. Need to export the project as Runnable JAR file for running the jar separately.
3. Do not run by just double clicking the jar in windows.